# Beaglebone Black Simulink mat-file logging

Tags: matlab, simulink, beagleboneblack

I have a Simulink model that runs on Beaglebone Black using Simulink/Matlab coder, embedded coder and Beaglebone Black hardware support.

With the model running on my board, I can talk to it using UDP and I am therefore sure that the model is running.

The generated program should be run as a stand-alone program and will be communicating with other programs and computers using the UDP blocks within Simulink.

I am trying to make some sort of data logging possible. When using "To file"-block logging, a file is gernerated on the BBB and its size increases as the program runs. However when sending stopModel(...) the program stops but the log file is corrupt according to Matlab.

The research I did suggests model_terminate() should/must be run to ensure all log-files are saved correctly.

Is there any other way to save .mat-files from a stand-alone program? How do I make sure the log files are created and readable even if I lose connection?

Comment: I should say that when building the model with a simulation time shorter than inf, the necessary files are, after the program has finished, created and are viewable in Matlab.

Comment: One solution is to send a boolean over UDP and have the model doing a simulation stop if that boolean is non zero. This works and might be the best way to deal with the model running as a stand-alone program.